Count of comments from me on a single repo
Is it possible to query the GitHub GraphQL API to retrieve the number of comments on issues/PRs on a single repo or an org for myself?
I think this one gives me all my comments:
query{
  user(login: "MyLogin") {
    issueComments {
      totalCount
    }
  }
}

